# How to: [REST] Get and Set Default Reviewers for a repository in Atlassian Stash (Bitbucket Server) programmatically using REST API

Tags: rest, pull-request, bitbucket-server

So... my current project includes making a script which will configure repositories programmatically on our Stash server (aka BitBucket server). This includes setting the default reviewers for each repository. Is there a REST API for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old issue, but just wanted to note that as of Bitbucket Server 5.1 the default reviewers REST API has been made public: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-retrieve-default-reviewers-via-rest-api-in-bitbucket-server-1047535034.html

recent version, curl examples at the bottom of the page https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-retrieve-default-reviewers-via-rest-api-in-bitbucket-server-1047535034.html

Answer (score 11):

There is [no documented REST API](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-8988?filter=allopenissues) for the default reviewers functionality, at least for the Stash version we are using (4.8.x) and probably the current version. And by "no documented API" I mean not just in the official REST API documentation, but anywhere on the web. Fortunately, there is a secret API that the plugin uses.

Long story short, here are the calls you need to do. They are plain GET, POST and DELETE on url. I will use curl for the examples for brevity:

---

- Get all default reviewers for a repository:

Do a GET on the following link:

```
curl -X GET -u (username):(password) (base_url)/rest/default-reviewers/latest/projects/(project_name)/repos/(repo_name)/conditions
```

Result will be a JSON list. Each item in the list includes the id of the entry in the list (which is different from user id) followed by information about the default reviewer rule.

---

- Add a default reviewer:

Do a POST on the following with the headers and data shown:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u (username):(password) (base_url)/rest/default-reviewers/latest/projects/(project_name)/repos/(repo_name)/condition --data-binary '{"sourceMatcher":{"id":"any","type":{"id":"ANY_REF"}},"targetMatcher":{"id":"refs/heads/master","type":{"id":"BRANCH"}},"reviewers":[{"id":XXXX}],"requiredApprovals":"0"}'
```

where XXXX is the user id (user name, e-mail or full name won't work). You can get a user's id using the standard REST API. Aka do a GET on: (base_url)/rest/api/1.0/users?filter=(username, email or full name)

---

- Remove a default reviewer:

Do a DELETE on the following

```
curl -X DELETE -u (username):(password) (base_url)/rest/default-reviewers/latest/projects/(project_name)/repos/(repo_name)/condition/YYY
```

Where YYY is the entry id in the default reviewers list (not the user id). If you know the user id, email, username, or full name of the user you want to delete, you can get all the default reviewers (see above), find the user you want, and then you can get the entry id of the list item.

---

One more thing: you can observe the default-reviewers plugin using the POST and DELETE commands using Chrome Inspector ("Network" tab), but the GET command is not used directly by the plugin (the user-facing part of it) and cannot be observed with Chrome (the reason I am making this post is because this GET command might be hard to figure out - it was for me)

Comment: For the GET, how would we filter by a unique id or branch name?  Assuming the list returned is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

To add to user1942541 's comprehensive answer, I can confirm that this is the only way to do it currently. We are planning to provide a proper, documented API for default reviewers at some point. Please watch https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-8988 for updates.

Comment: It appears that the support has been added. The mentioned Jira issue was marked as Fixed on 07/Jun/2017 11:43 PM with a FixVersion of 5.1.0.